# how to download and save media files in internal storage android java

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-storage, android-internal-storage

I want to download some audio files from the internet. I want to use downloadmanager to download this file but I don't know how to save these files to a specific internal storage location in android. `InternalStorage/folder/filename.mp3` (so I can access them easily).

```
manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("URL");
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
                long reference = manager.enqueue(request);
```

It is useful for downloading. But we cannot specify the location for these files.

So how to specify these files to be saved in the internal storage at a specific location. And also, how to `access` and `delete` these files.

Please don't devote this question as I got confused while going through many articles.

if any other better alternative or any suggestion comment down

Comment: Of course you can. Better look at request.setDestination... functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add this line to save file:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARM,mp3name);
```

> to delete this file

```
File file = new 
File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS),"Fav_Ringtone.mp3");

file.delete();
```

> to read this file

```
File file= newFile(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_ALARMS),"Fav_Ringtone.mp3");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just wanted to know whether the downloaded file exists or not and your code helped

Comment: can I know how can I share the video using this method?

Answer (score 4):

Check the request.setDestination functions [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request)
To Store file in External App-Specific Directory [example: "*external/Android/data/your_app_name/filePath_you_set_in_function*”], use like below:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setDescription("Selected Video is being downloaded");
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setTitle("Downloading Video");
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
//Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName); //To Store file in External Public Directory use "setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)"
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)
mContext.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

And if you want to download it to another place you need to move it after your download gets finished, by using IO streams. You can use a broadcast receiver to perform this task once the DownloadManager has finished downloading. You can use FileProvider to open the file with another app in Android version 10 or above.

Comment: "Path" is not a public dir so that will not go. And they are no callbacks.

Comment: Sorry, but your update makes it even worse by supplying a full parh. And the legacy permission request is not needed. Never.

Comment: @blackapps, This working well at my end. Please share the other option if you have one.

Comment: @Akki but how to retrieve and delete that specific file. (I am using `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir`)

Comment: @SachinBurdak, You have already answered!. yes, to get the specific file use "context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName)"